# Trying to install Google Maps module onto python syntax error via pip

Tags: python, pip

Hi I'm fairly new to python but wanted to ask about this issue I'm having. I know I have to add my version of python (3.9.0) to environmental variables which I did. I also confirmed `pip` is checked in optional features when I went through the run menu. When I go into the windows command prompt it recognizes my python version but when I type `"pip install GoogleMaps"` I get:

> ```
> pip install GoogleMaps
>
>      File "<stdin>", line 1
>        pip install GoogleMaps
>            ^
>    SyntaxError: invalid syntax
> ```

Maybe I am still doing something wrong but I just can't get to the bottom of this. Any response on what I could try or what I maybe missing here would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you running it in a python instance? In other words, are you typing this at the `>>>` prompt?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+SyntaxError

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are in a python instance.
when you open the command line you don't type `python` and instead run the command

```
`pip install googlemaps`
```

without typing `python` to install the correct pip module.

Note: depending on operating system you may need to run
`pip3 install googlemaps`

Comment: >pip install GoogleMaps
'pip' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: try pip3 install googlemaps

Comment: My bad accidentally pressed enter without commenting. I was going to say you were right I was in a python instance but when I run it as administrator for command prompt I get the error I wrote above as well for pip3.

Comment: did it solve the issue or are you still having problems?

Comment: Yeah maybe I'm misunderstanding your comment but it seems what your saying is run the command in the command prompt as administrator which I said I tried before although I messed up by saying its the same error. It actually says "'pip' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: Sorry it was my bad I somehow wrote the exact opposite of what I meant, don't ask me how...... you need to run it as user NOT as admin

Comment: When I downloaded pip separately after having adding both the pip file location and previously the python edition to environment variable path and open the pip file I'm getting:  WARNING: The scripts pip.exe, pip3.9.exe and pip3.exe are installed in 'C:\Users\john\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Scripts' which is not on PATH.
  Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.

Comment: yeah even just as user I'm getting:  C:\Users\john>pip install GoogleMaps
'pip' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: I don't know why but your pip is not in path. Add this to path C:\Users\john\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Scripts

Comment: or uninstall and reinstall python and make sure to check the box that adds pip to path

Comment: Just added it to the path and ran pip install GoogleMaps and it worked! Thanks for you help, I appreciate it.

Comment: if you don't mind pls check the question as answered thanks.